# Máscara de campos de texto não funciona no ambiente mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Utilizei o seguinte código em jQuery para mascarar o campo `telefone` por exemplo.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#telefone").mask("(99)9999.9999");
});
```

Este código funciona perfeitamente no computador, porém no celular, só aparece a formatação esperando ser digitado algo, mas quando é digitado alguma coisa, a mascara não é aplicada, misturando assim, os números com os outros caracteres.

### Exemplo do que acontece:

```js
jQuery(function($){
$("#telefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<strong>No desktop: </strong>
<input type="text" id="telefone">
<br><br>
<strong>No celular: </strong>
<input type="text" value="(__)____.____">
```

Alguém tem ideia de como corrigir isso?

*Observação: Se você digitar a quantidade de números correta do telefone, mesmo que tenha outros caracteres no campo, ele aplica o filtro ao pressionar enter, ou clicar fora do campo.*

Comment: Ja tive esse problema também - pra mim a solução foi usar uma mascara em javascript puro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é usar uma mascara em puro javascript. Usando *regex* pode ser algo como:

```js
document.getElementById('telefone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var aux = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !aux[2] ? aux[1] : '(' + aux[1] + ') ' + aux[2] + (aux[3] ? '-' + aux[3] : '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="telefone" placeholder="(99) 9999.9999"/>
```

Comment: Feito, funcionou perfeitamente! Valeu @LucasCosta